# Call JS function from another file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in a separate JavaScript file that I would like to call in a React component - how can I achieve this?

I'm trying to create a slideshow, and in `slideshow.js`, I have this function that increases the current slide index, like so:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

In `Homepage.jsx`, I have a "next" button that should call `plusSlides` from `slideshow.js` when it is clicked, like so:

```
class NextButton extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick (event) {
        script.plusSlides(1); // I don't know how to do this properly...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <a className="next" onClick={this.onClick}>
                &#10095;
            </a>
        );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can export it, or am I missing your question

```
//slideshow.js
export const plusSlides = (n)=>{
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

and import it where you need to

```
//Homepage.js
import {plusSlides} from './slideshow'

handleClick (event) {
        plusSlides(1); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I figured out what I was doing wrong, and now it works perfectly! :^)

Comment: can you explain it in react Hook?

Comment: pretty much exactly the same thing, except you wouldnt call it inside a class function