# React.js / CRA, How to call or import a javaScript function from another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

My code is getting longer so I decided to transfer them to other javaScript file.

I followed this [relevant topic regarding my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262599/call-js-function-from-another-file-in-react) but Why I getting an error i just copy and paste everything?

In above link here's the code

```
//slideshow.js
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

//Home.js
class NextButton extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick (event) {
        script.plusSlides(1); // I don't know how to do this properly...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <a className="next" onClick={this.onClick}>
                &#10095;
            </a>
        );
    } 
}
```

This my error "Attempted import error: 'plusSlides' is not exported from '../plusSides file'."

I used react.js CRA is there something i need to configure to fix this?

Comment: You need to show us the contents of `plusSlides` to help you. And also the file that imports it. It sounds like you've forgotten to export it or is importing it in a wrong way

Comment: Code added now. Also I tried to import like this  `import plusSlides from 'path-of-the-file'` also i tried this `import { plusSlides  } from 'path-of-the-file'`  but still error.

Answer (score 2):

It must have worked. Only thing you need is babel to transpile es6 (which I assume you have as you have used react CRA). There is another way of doing it, i.e using default export

#### slideshow.js

```js
export default (n)=>{
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

and importing this function like this in Home.js

#### Home.js

```js
import anyname from './slideshow.js' //I am assuming you have slideshow.js and Home.js in same directory

handleClick (event) {
    anyname(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really giving space followed by the word 'file'?? Don't you think it should be imported like:

> import plusSlides from '../plusSides';

Also, see what you're exporting from that file. If it is a default import then you can import by any name you want, otherwise you have to give same names in the export and imports. Remember, you can only make one default export per file.