# My css doesn't load automatically in react with vite

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have some css and js files that I try to import into a view in React with vite so that it loads the styles, but it doesn't load, and when I enter the view, I have to comment and uncomment the import in code for the styles to be read.

I leave a capture of how I import the files in the view.

[image]

My folder tree.

[image: My folder tree.]

The js file "custom.min.js"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The import path `/src/*` maybe is wrong. I may need more info, but if this file you've shown is **inside** the `src` folder then the import path is incorrect. To be explicit, you need a *relative* path to any .css files.

Now I may be mistaken, but the `js` imports need to be named. I can see you're using TypeScript *and* you're using import statements, so I am only guessing but you'll need to name the import or import the specific "thing" you export in the `js` files. This can look like the following:

```js
import fit from "/src/assets/js/*";
```

or

```js
import { fit } from "/src/assets/js/*";
```

and the export in the `custom.min.js` file should look like:

```js
export default fit;
```

or

```js
export { fit };
```

---

Now for your `.css` and `.js`, if this is your directory:

```
__src
  |___ assets
  |
  |___ components
  |
  |
  |___ App.tsx
  |___ App.css
  |___ ...(everything else that lives in `src/` from a `create-react-app`)
```

then you will need to import the `.css` file like so into the `App.tsx`:

```
import "./assets/style/style.css"
```

You can *optionally* leave out the extension, but I am not 100% sure for `.css` files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, the css and js file is inside SRC.

Comment: I need to export my js functions??? My functions use jquey inside.

Comment: So this particular `.tsx` file is not outside of the `src` folder. You do need to export the functions. Can you show exactly where the *.tsx file is? Youll need the *relative* path, so your import will look something like `../assets/js/*` or `../assets/css/*`

Comment: If you are using TypeScript with react, I would recommend changing your `js` files to `ts` so you get the benefit of typing your JavaScript. To talk about how that code may be exported/imported is another topic. You may want to just test to see if you can get a basic file, `hello-world.js` or `hello-world.ts` (They would be interchangeable) imported into your `App.tsx` file and see if you can log something to the console while running your react app.

Comment: I'd also appreciate any up-votes for any comments or answers! :) if you need any clarification, feel free to ask!

Comment: None of the solutions work. Neither with the css file nor with the js.
The js do not have any business logic, they are only useful for component animations.

Comment: Where is the `.tsx` file in relation to the `.css` file? At the end of the `custom.min.js` if you don't have an export statement then none of the `js` file will be executed.

See this post for a more explicit answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262599/call-js-function-from-another-file-in-react

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242556/discussion-between-lua-python-java-and-gerson-saul-malca-bazan).

Comment: The problem is that the js functions and css styles do not load automatically when I enter the view, I have to remove the import lines and reload the view, then re-insert the same lines for the styles and functions to load correctly .

Answer (score 0):

In case you're trying to use an absolute path for your imports, you need to remove the backslash before the 'src'.

In your case, the imports are prefixed with '/' so it looks for the 'src' folder inside the current directory, 'src/components/organisms/sidebar/src/{your imports}'.

Choosing between relative and absolute imports is a matter of a personal opinion as they both have trade-offs, [this will make it clearer](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understand-and-configure-absolute-import-paths-in-javascript-5cde3be2630d), [and this](https://medium.com/beqode/absolute-vs-relative-import-paths-nodejs-1e4efa65a7bb).